# char * is slower than string in release compile

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I made my own string type in C++ and I want to test the speed of `std::string` vs `my string` in insert (equal =) action.

```
class mystring
{
private:

    char * _cont;

public:

    mystring(const char * str) {

        size_t getLen = strlen(str);
        _cont = (char *) malloc(getLen + 1);
        memcpy(_cont, str, getLen);
        _cont[getLen + 1]= '\0';
    }
};

int main() {

    char * str = new char [12];
    strcpy(str,"Hello world");

    auto start_t = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        string storage(str);
    }
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start_t).count() << " milliseconds\n";

    start_t = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        mystring storage2(str);
    }
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start_t).count() << " milliseconds\n";

    return 0;
}
```

In this code I created a loop for string to get my `char * str` and then same process for my own string variable
in **debug** mode of compiler I got this result:

```
1108 milliseconds
531 milliseconds
```

Here my string is 2x faster than `std::string` to get the value (equal)

but I found out one important thing, when I change compiler mode to **Release**, the result are really different. std::string` is 5x faster.

```
93 milliseconds
472 milliseconds
```

Why `mystring` is 5x slower than `std::string` in Release mode? What can I do to fix it?

**I realized if I use**

```
mystring(const char * str) {
        size_t getLen = strlen(str);
        char temp[getLen + 1];
        memcpy(temp, str, getLen);
        _cont = temp;
    }
```

**`mystring` is faster 2x in Release mode but when `mystring()` done, nothing save in `char * _cont` because function is done and temp deleted auto ... is there any way to do this action and hold the temp in `_cont` after function done ?**

Comment: Benchmarking in debug mode is pointless. Only benchmark with optimizations turned on.

Comment: Just use a profiler. Other people shouldn't have to do that for you.

Comment: yes but what can i do to arrive string benchamrk? string do same thing to get and save the content ... no ?

Comment: Well, most std::string implementations use small-string optimization, which is of great benefit (no dynamic allocations for small strings).

Comment: Look at the assembly output to be sure what the difference is.

Comment: Chances are that `std::string` does not perform dynamic memory allocation because the strings are so small that small-string optimisation (SSO) can be applied.

Comment: Chances are that your loop will get completely eliminated by the optimizer too.

Comment: Most C++ standard libraries are highly optimized. You won’t be able to achieve a performance anywhere near with a naive implementation like this.

Comment: `_cont[getLen + 1]= '\0';` should be `_cont[getLen]= '\0';`, otherwise you invoke undefined behaviour by accessing out of bounds.

Comment: but i i change my (hello world) content to a content with length more than 2000, my string is equal with string !

Comment: I see a `malloc` and no `free` here. Your benchmark should take the liberation cost into account (because this liberation is performed with the std::string data)

Comment: The code has undefined behaviour.   `_cont = malloc(getLen + 1)` means that valid indices for `_cont` run from `0` to `getLen`.   Setting `_cont[getLen+ 1] = 0` therefore modifies a character one past the end.    No point in puzzling over performance when code has such undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm wondering that you actually measure anything, because you are not using either `storage` or `storage2` in the rest of the code. I would expect any good compiler to completely optimize them out in the release mode, seems that your compiler is not very good at optimizing unnecessary code.

Comment: Please, only try to beat `std::string` performance, when you're an experienced c++ programmer. Looking at your questions, you're a beginner now.

Comment: About your last question: it faster, because it doesn't do any heap allocations. You just allocate an array on the stack, copy the string there. When the function returns, your string has vanished. You can do the same, as current `std::string` implementors do: there's a little buffer in the string itself. if the assigned string is short, then they don't allocate, but copy the string into this little buffer. If it is not short, then they allocate from the heap. And they usually apply a trick, so the little buffer is actually a union with other parts of the string.

Comment: @idmean: actually, `std::string` optimized for small strings. If you use long strings, and copy them often, you can create an implementation, which is much faster than current implementations of `std::string`.

Comment: "What can I do to fix it?" Build up 20+ years worth of design iterations with a team of talented programmers, just like std::string authors have done. Failing that, study their design very carefully. Stackoverflow won't do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why mystring is 5x slower than string in Release mode?

Probably because you did not implement optimizations that your standard library does. Your micro benchmark is particularly favorable to the small string optimization, where the implementation avoids allocating any dynamic memory when the string fits in the space of the string object itself.

> what can i do to fix it?

Implement the same optimizations that your standard library uses. Then again, why would you not use the already optimized string implementation?

---

> i realized if i using
>
> ```
> char temp[getLen + 1];
> memcpy(temp, str, getLen);
> _cont = temp;
> ```
>
> mystring is faster 2x in Release mode but when mystring() done, nothing save in char * _cont because function is done and temp deleted auto

The behaviour of accessing the memory pointed by `_cont` after the function returns is undefined. The problem is much worse than "nothing saved".

> is there any way to do this action and hold the temp in _cont after function done ?

No. There is no way to make prevent an automatic array from being destroyed at the end of its scope. The memory of the string has to be either within the string object, or be allocated dynamically.

---

P.S your string cheats in the benchmark by leaking the allocated memory instead of releasing it like the standard string does.

Comment: @myOwnWays `typedef std::string mystring;` ;)

Comment: @myOwnWays see the source code of your standard library to see how they have been implemented. If that source is not available, then see the source of libstdc++ or libc++ for example.

Comment: @myOwnWays - Your implementation is like 15 lines. If you check the `<xstring>` header in VC++, it is 4000 lines long. Seems they have put in a lot of extra effort.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is true, that your string class does not contain the optimizations that an implementation of `std::string` would contain. Most importantly, your implementation does not have the small-string optimization that will store the characters of small strings right in the `std::string` object, avoiding the dynamic memory allocation in these cases.

However, that's not the only reason why your `mystring` class is so much slower. And I want to point out where your implementation looses time:

1. You are leaking your allocations. While at first glance this looks a bit like cheating, the missing `free()` actually looses you time: Since you did not free your memory, the next `malloc()` cannot reuse it. As such, it has to use fresh memory for all ten million allocations, so it must request more than 120 megabytes from the kernel. This alone is considerable overhead. The fact that you never reuse your memory also means that your code is less cache friendly than it could be.

   As such, simply adding a destructor with

   ```
   ~mystring() {
       free(_cont);
   }
   ```

   to your class saves roughly 20% of the time on my machine.
2. Your constructor can be simplified significantly by using `strdup()`:

   ```
   mystring(const char* str) {
       _cont = strdup();
   }
   ```

   Again, this draws on the wisdom of the standard libraries implementators to gain another 10% by fusing the string length determination with the allocation and copy-over.

---

For completeness, I have pimped your benchmark a little bit:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

class StringBase {
    protected:
        char* data;
};

class String1 : private StringBase {
    public:
        String1(const char* str) {
            size_t getLen = strlen(str);
            data = (char *) malloc(getLen + 1);
            memcpy(data, str, getLen);
            data[getLen + 1]= '\0';
        }
};

class String2 : private StringBase {
    public:
        String2(const char* str) {
            size_t getLen = strlen(str);
            data = (char *) malloc(getLen + 1);
            memcpy(data, str, getLen);
            data[getLen + 1]= '\0';
        }
        ~String2() { free(data); }
};

class String3 : private StringBase {
    public:
        String3(const char* str) { data = strdup(str); }
        ~String3() { free(data); }
};

class String4 : private StringBase {
    public:
        String4(const char* str) {
            size_t getLen = strlen(str);
            data = new char[getLen + 1];
            memcpy(data, str, getLen);
            data[getLen + 1]= '\0';
        }
};

class String5 : private StringBase {
    public:
        String5(const char* str) {
            size_t getLen = strlen(str);
            data = new char[getLen + 1];
            memcpy(data, str, getLen);
            data[getLen + 1]= '\0';
        }
        ~String5() { delete[] data; }
};

template<class T>
void benchmarkString(const char* comment, const char* str) {
    //fork a new process for each benchmark to stop the benchmarks from influencing each other
    if(pid_t child = fork()) {
        waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
    } else {
        std::cout << comment;
        auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            T storage(str);
        }
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime).count() << " milliseconds\n";
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main() {
    const char* str = "Hello World!";
    benchmarkString<std::string>("std::string: ", str);
    benchmarkString<String1>("original mystring implementation: ", str);
    benchmarkString<String2>("destructor added: ", str);
    benchmarkString<String3>("destructor added and use of strdup(): ", str);
    benchmarkString<String4>("C++ new used instead of malloc(): ", str);
    benchmarkString<String5>("destructor added: ", str);
}
```

With this benchmark, I get the following output on my machine:

```
std::string: 372 milliseconds
original mystring implementation: 931 milliseconds
destructor added: 771 milliseconds
destructor added and use of strdup(): 709 milliseconds
C++ new used instead of malloc(): 952 milliseconds
destructor added: 844 milliseconds
```

Now, if I replace the source string `"Hello World!"` with

```
const char* str = "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789";
```

I get this:

```
std::string: 1132 milliseconds
original mystring implementation: /* thrashing */
destructor added: 1036 milliseconds
destructor added and use of strdup(): 965 milliseconds
C++ new used instead of malloc(): /* thrashing */
destructor added: 1100 milliseconds
```

The difference is, that now the string is too long for the small string optimization, and suddenly my own class outperforms `std::string`.

This may be largely due to the fact that the `new`/`delete` pair is not as efficient as `malloc()`/`free()` on my machine, as I'd bet on `std::string` to use `new`/`delete`. But it's also due to the fact that my implementation does not bother checking whether the small string optimization can be applied.